# Include path to Boost area on local machine

Tags: gcc, boost

I´m a newbie and I want to compile a framework that requires gcc and boost. I have progressed according to comments in makefile (I have already installed gcc-7 and boost), however I got stuck there:

```
# Include path to Boost area on local machine
#
#worked with both CENTOS and Ubuntu: export BOOST    := /usr/
export BOOST    := /usr/
#export BOOST    := /sarc/spa/tools/conda/envs/spa-1
```

I have no idea what I should do with it. I´m using Ubuntu through Windows.
Thanks for your time.